# Using DevExpress to create Winform Dashboard with Portlets

Tags: devexpress, portlet, dashboard

I'm brand new at my company where we use DevExpress.  I haven't used DevExpress before so I've been trolling Google and DE website looking for some specific functionality.  Our winform app needs the opening form to be a dashboard where the use can add our custom portlets to it and then move those around within the dashboard layout.  One of my developers was showing me the capabilities of the Layout Manager and it's customization mode but that isn't cutting it.  It feels way too much like a developer's IDE to create a custom form.

Am I out of luck using DevExpress components to create a dashboard interface?  If so, any recommendations for another component?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this:
[DevExpress Dockable Windows](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5368)